# AngularJS: format element text with a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element

```
<td colspan="3" class="linkCol"><a ng-href="{{ad.url}}" target="_blank" title="{{ad.url}}">Link</a></td>
```

And a function `getDomain(url)` that returns domain.

I want the `'.linkCol'` element to have text returned by `getDomain(ad.url)`.

It's all inside an ng-repeat. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`getDomain()` needs to be added to the scope in the controller...

```
$scope.getDomain = function(url) {
    // ...
    return domain;
};
```

Then you can use it in your view...

```
<td colspan="3" class="linkCol">
    <a ng-href="{{ad.url}}" target="_blank" title="{{ad.url}}">{{ getDomain(ad.url) }}</a>
</td>
```